# unable to connect i9100 in cwm recovery mode

Tags: updates, usb, recovery-mode, usb-connection-mode

phone; i9100 maguro galaxy nexus. From CM, I got a message stating a new update was available: the CM11. I accepted. The update failed to install. Now on reboot the phone enters CWM Recovery mode. BUT IT WILL NOT CONNECT TO MY PC TO ENABLE ME TO TRANSFER ANY ZIP FILES to my phone, and so I cannot install any older CM10 versions. HOW TO CONNECT THE PHONE TO PC IN CWM RECOVERY MODE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) a try, and use `adb push </source/on/PC/file.zip> <target/on/Nexus/file.zip>` to transfer the files.

I you don't have ADB installed on your machine yet, and don't want to install the full SDK, take a look at [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) Also, for more information on ADB, there's always our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) as a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Well, I can find the path and file on my PC. But the phone does not show as a mounted device, so have no idea what the location and path could be to the phone.  Interestingly, Heimdall will connect to the phone when the phone is in "download mode", but no path is given.  The trouble I am having with Heimdall is finding any valid tar.gz file that can be downloaded and flashed to the phone. I thought the easier approach was to somehow get a CMxxx.zip file onto the internal SD card and then unzip via the CWM recovery mode. But cannot push the file to card yet.

Comment: The device does not show "mounted" with ADB. You can see whether it is *connected* using `adb devices`. You can explore it via `adb shell` at the command line. For details on that, please see our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) and [command-line tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/command-line/info) – a complete excurse on command-line usage and ADB would be a bit out of scope here, but those wikis hold some first-aid and links to further information.

Comment: "adb devices" shows no devices connected.

Comment: "adb shell" returns "device not found".

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I got my phone working. 

Step 1: follow the adb configuration guide per the tag-wiki above.  

Step 2: mount the data... 
$ adb shell
~ # mount /data
~ # exit    

Step 3: push the file to the right place!  
adb push cm-10.2.0-maguro.zip /sdcard/0/ 

Step 4: on phone in recovery page, install zip from sdcard in the /0 directory

Comment: Glad to read you've managed to solve the issue! To indicate it's solved, mind to "accept" the answer by ticking the check-mark next to it? Only the OP (you) can do that :)